# How to start loading big background image earlier than other external resources?

Tags: image, http, httprequest

I am trying to think of a solution to start loading a background image after loading *.html or *.php, and not waiting to load *.css or *.js. When I look in Web Inspector on the Network tab how my page is loading, I see that images start loading only after all scripts and style sheets are loaded.

Comment: What?? Sorry it is not clear what the question is here.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be a little more specific?
If you want to pre-load you will need JS support, so that can be done once the JS is working and if you are writting non-intrusive JS then you probably will have to wait until the document is loaded.

Comment: I mean... then i look in Web Inspector on Network tab how load's my page, i see that images start loads, only after all scripts and style sheets are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are seeing is due to the fact that browsers limit the number of simultaneous connections. Since your styles and scripts are likely in your `<head>` section, they're bound to be called before the background images. Therefore images must load after styles and scripts - doubly so if the style defining the background image is in your stylesheet.

There isn't really any way to avoid this on the first load, but if you're setting the correct cache headers the images will be instant afterward.